# How can I stop my custom UITableViewCell backgroundImage from being stretchable?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiimageview

If I create a background image for my table cell in the init method of my UITableViewCell subclass, the image comes out exactly how I drew it, and `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` simply adds a gap around it.

But if instead I create the background image in my tableView's `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method and set it, changing the cell height will now stretch the image.

I need to create the background views in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, as the background changes for different rows. How can I make my image's size fixed again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried setting the contentMode to UIViewContentModeCenter for the backgroundView of the cell?

put it here

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     cell.backgroundView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
}
```

Comment: Makes no difference, I'm afraid.

Comment: I've checked my edited answer in practice and it worked, do you get notifications for edited answers?

Comment: Sorry - just saw it. There doesn't seem to be any notification for edited answers. It works perfectly now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could create something with:

```
UIView *cellBackView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
<insert image>;
cell.backgroundView = cellBackView;
```

My guess is the backgroundView gets strechted automatically, but you could make sure the image isn't stretched on that view by setting a width and height. This way, you can do whatever you like with that view.

Comment: I've given this a try but it doesn't seem to do anything :(